Show gitea contributions heatmap on homepage
Is there a way to show my Gitea contributions heatmap on the homepage?
I would like to show my gitea contributions heat map on the homepage. However, there doesn't seem to be any API or variables I can use to get that information. Is there any exposed APIs i can use to query this information?
